# R: xmlParse incorrectly "adding" extra " AND " to URL link, parsing fails

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing, pubmed

I am attempting to parse xml output from the NIH's pubmed system. I have already generated my URLs to parse, but the xmlParse() function appears to be adding extra " AND " text into my URLs that contain operators.

For example:

```
url <- 'http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=smith+m[author]+AND+science[journal]'
di <- xmlParse(url)
dl <- xmlToList(di)
```

This results a "NULL" IdList (where the results should be):

```
> dl[["IdList"]]
NULL
```

Checking the QueryTranslation reveals the problem (see: extra AND):

```
> dl[["QueryTranslation"]]
[1] "smith+m[author] AND +AND+science[journal]"
```

Any idea what's going on there? This is occurring with every search field or type of query that I construct that has an operator such as "AND" or "OR".

A clean parse that finds 20 papers for reference:

```
> url <- 'http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=smith+bm[author]'
> di <- xmlParse(url)
> dl <- xmlToList(di)
> length(dl[["IdList"]])
[1] 20
```

Comment: To make life easier, you could use one of the already built R clients, e.g., https://github.com/ropensci/rentrez or https://github.com/ropenhealth/rpubmed (i think there are others as well)

Comment: Browsing to the first address yielded a different `QueryTranslation` than what you saw. Have you tried looking at the transaction using a debugging proxy (such as Fiddler on Windows, or mitmproxy on Mac or Linux)?

Comment: PubMed will modify or add additional terms to any search to optimize retrieval using automatic term mapping and their search rules, including AND between two concepts which is happening here.  Try running the search at PubMed and check the Search Details on the right, but even science[journal] translates to something else and you may want "science"[journal]

Comment: Also, just let xmlParse handle the blank spaces and try `url <- 'http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=smith m[author] AND science[journal]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to do this from scratch instead of a package I mentioned above:

Use `httr` first, to retrieve payload, which doesn't mess up the URL

```
library("XML")
library("httr")
url <- 'http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=smith+m[author]+AND+science[journal]'
res <- GET(url)
di <- xmlParse(content(res, "text"))
dl <- xmlToList(di)
unname(unlist(dl[["IdList"]]))

[1] "25745065" "25430773" "25395526" "25104368" "24458648" "24264993" "24052300" "23869013"
[9] "23363771" "22936773" "22116878" "21940895" "21330515" "21097923" "20966241" "20150469"
[17] "19407144" "19150811" "19119232" "19119226"
```